# MVC populate textbox from one view to another view on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Good day. 
I had been to a lot of forums and still was not able to grasp the solution. the system has this code wherein a user clicks a textbox then a new "_blank" will appear containing the table. when a user clicks select from that table, the page closes and the id of the user selected will be passed to the parent page. how can I do this? I tried certain scripts found in some forums but doesn't seem to work.

This is my code to the child page:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ID)</th>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Fullname)</th>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Address)</th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model){
 <tr>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fullname)</td>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</td>
 <td>
 <a href="@Url.Action("Close", new { ID = item.ID })" class="btn btn-warning" id="close" > Create <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 }</table>

 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Showw", new { page, searchString = Request.QueryString["searchString"] }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#close").click(function () {
var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
myWindow.document.write("");
setTimeout(function () { myWindow.close(); }, 1000);
});
</script>
}
```

I have a code to retrieve the id but can't seem to find the code fitting to transfer it to the parent page as soon as the this(child page) closes. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Indeed of opening a new blank page, you can open a bootstrap model

```
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>   

@Html.TextBox("displayVal","",new { id= "displayVal" })>    

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr  data-dismiss="modal" class="val" data-val="001">
                        <td>001</td>
                        <td>One</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr  data-dismiss="modal" class="val" data-val="002">
                        <td>002</td>
                        <td>Two</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr  data-dismiss="modal" class="val" data-val="003">
                        <td>003</td>
                        <td>Three</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".val").click(function () {
           $("#displayVal").val($(this).data("val"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

When user clicks on the table row it will display/pass the value to parent page